# setting up Django for internal web server ( from window to linux ) , what exactly do I need to install ?

Tags: python, linux, django, python-2.7

I'm the beginner. I'm trying to deploy Django app to the internal web-server that is control by admin. The apache linux box with python 2.6 installed  , but I am using 2.7 - on windows - other than following settings from  http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html

My question is , what are the installations that I have to ask the admin to install in the linux box ?

1. Install **Django** following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/
   ?
2. Python **version** : remove 2.6 and replaced with 2.7 python ? <- does it necessary ?
3. What about all the
   **packages** ? For example I use pandas. I usually do

   "pip install
       pandas"

   on my windows,  do I need to ask admin to install that as well ?

If I don't use Django , but normal html - I usually just FTP to

```
/virtualhosts/mycompany.com/reports/www/index.html
```

and I would be able to see it. For Django I have >

```
mysite1/
    manage.py
    mysite2/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

Do i upload all **mysite1** to replace **index.html**  ( /virtualhosts/mycompany.com/reports/www/ ) ?

Sorry i am truly beginner here.

Comment: Definitely look into virtualenv. Install python 2.7 as you need that for Django 1.7. Then install packages into the virtualenv as needed. So things like `pip install django` ,`pip install pandas`, etc. Check that the packages were correctly installed with `pip freeze`. You will need to activate the virtualenv so that the Django site uses the correct packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask admin to install [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) so you will be able to install everything else on your own.
Anyway you will have to get ssh access to server to be able run your projects, so ask admin for it.

1. To install Django you just `pip install django` and you will get latest version
2. Python 2.7 is not necessary, but desirable since you might face problems on 2.6 like some modules you install might not be supported by 2.6 version
3. If you've followed official tutorial, yu should have been created `requirements.txt` in your projects, just find this file and send it to your admin, asking him to `pip install -r requirments.txt`. If not - you should read about this file cause it kind of must-have in project.
4. FTP upload - yes, you have to upload whole folder `mysite1`
   I recommend you check out this thing, cause it is very easy and useful, especially if admin will help you to install it [virtualenv wrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Edit: also consider installing [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) alongside with Windows(it has such option out-of-box) You will fall in love with it for sure and will not be willing to return on Windows(except to play games if you do)